# unrecognized expression: jQuery syntax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $("#divItemName input:[type='text']").val(itemName);
```

i have the above jQuery line of code. It works properly in jQuery 1.7.2 but in jquery-2.1.3, it throws the error below.

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #divItemName input:[type='text']

What is the correct syntax for this in jquery-2.1.3?

Comment: I've always used `input[type='text']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valid CSS selector will be

```
$("#divItemName input[type='text']").val(itemName);
```

Colon `:` in front of attribute selector `[type='text']` looks weird even for older jQuery version. While `#divItemName input[type='text']` is perfectly valid CSS syntax, it's not jQuery specific thing.